# シェルで特定の文字から特定の文字までを抜き出す方法

Tags: linux, shellscript, unix

下記のtoken.txtからaccess_tokenの中身（ya〜rJ）だけを標準出力させる方法を教えて下さい。

```
    $ cat token.txt 
     "access_token": "ya29.GltzBPiM93Gz67sL67VdZfQ5IDySH7iWenpufvl3dAEPnH7DeUxdL45s1pgnl7Ixs2rsj56dXygMkphYuvVxFYGqiz9qfb3IRqqyNqLJjtuIvVfznZBu2KPaLOrJ",
```

Comment: GNU grep を使ってもよいのであれば、`grep -Po ': "\K[^"]+' token.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat token.txt | tr -d '" ' | awk -F: '{ print $2 }'
```

`tr`コマンドで不要なクォート(と空白)を予め削除、`awk`コマンドで2列目の値(=今回必要なaccess_token)を出力しています。

Answer (score 1):

もっと汎用的に、pretty-print 形式の JSON データから `access_token` の値を取り出す、という要件で考えてみる。(値にはエスケープが必要な文字を含まなものとする)

```
$ sed -n 's/^ *"access_token": "\([^"]*\)",\{0,1\}$/\1/p' data.json
```